# How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression using Julia?

Tags: julia

I have two separate dictionaries defined. I am wondering if there is an elegant, single expression way that I can merge these two dictionaries into one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using the `merge()` function. Here's a quick example:

```
julia> a = Dict("One" => 1.0, "Two" => 2.0)
Dict{String,Float64} with 2 entries:
  "One" => 1.0
  "Two" => 2.0

julia> b = Dict("Three" => 3, "Four" => 4)
Dict{String,Int64} with 2 entries:
  "Three" => 3
  "Four"  => 4

julia> c = merge(a, b)
Dict{String,Float64} with 4 entries:
  "One"   => 1.0
  "Two"   => 2.0
  "Three" => 3.0
  "Four"  => 4.0
```

See the Julia docs [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.merge) for more examples and functionality related to `merge()`. The `merge` function creates a new, separate dictionary and returns it. There is also a mutating `merge!` function which modifies its first argument:

```
julia> merge!(a, b)
Dict{String,Float64} with 4 entries:
  "One"   => 1.0
  "Two"   => 2.0
  "Three" => 3.0
  "Four"  => 4.0

julia> a
Dict{String,Float64} with 4 entries:
  "One"   => 1.0
  "Two"   => 2.0
  "Three" => 3.0
  "Four"  => 4.0
```

Note that `merge!` returns the merged array which is the original dictionary `a` modified.